# Update date in Android DatePickerDialog with Today button without closing dialog

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'd like to have a date picker dialog with a "Today" button. If I click on Today button, it should reset datepicker to current date, without closing the dialog.

I have the following code:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.MyDialogStyle, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Today", (dialog, which) -> {
      datePickerDialog.updateDate(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
});
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Expected behavior: set datepicker's date to current date without closing the dialog.

Actual behavior: dialog closes, date doesn't change.

I also tried with new DatePickerDialog(...), and

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), null);
```

but it still doesn't work, only closes the dialog.
What am I missing here?

Is there a way to update datepicker's date programmatically without closing the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default click button calls also `dismiss()` method to close the `DatePickerDialog`. It applies also to the `DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL` button which you use for 'Today'.

Probably the simplest way to avoid this is to override the `DatePickerDialog.dismiss()` method and skip calling `super.dismiss()` if the 'Today' button was clicked.
Here is my working code in Kotlin I use for the same purpose (`Today` button for the `DatePickerDialog`). I use `skipDismiss` flag to know when to skip dismissal.

```
val datePickerDialog = object : DatePickerDialog(
        this@MainActivity,
        settings.currentTheme,
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, chosenYear, chosenMonth, dayOfMonth ->
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, chosenYear)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, chosenMonth)
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            text_view_chosen_date.text = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US).format(calendar.time)
        },
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
) {
    override fun dismiss() {
        if (!skipDismiss) {
            super.dismiss()
        } else {
            skipDismiss = false
        }
    }
}
```

And of course the 'Today' button listener should set the `skipDismiss` flag to true when called. Here is my code for that:

```
datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Today") { dialog, which ->
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    (dialog as DatePickerDialog).updateDate(
            today.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            today.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    )
    skipDismiss = true;
}
```

Comment: This is working just as expected, or even better, because I don't have to maintain the boolean value, just set it to true by the neutral button listener. Thanks a lot! :)